# Scanning barcodes in WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, barcode, barcode-scanner

I have been searching for a while but can not seem to find an answer..

I have a bar code scanner hooked up to my computer and it acts as a keyboard wedge. The Scanner is setup to send me a StartOfTransmission and EndofTransmission character so that I know to process all the keys in-between and do some action.

in the shell of my application I have the following code...

```
private void Window_PreviewTextInput(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = BarcodeScanner.Instance.ProcessTextInput(this, e.Text, e.Device, e.Timestamp);
}
```

This works great if I have focus on the main window OR a control that does not process spaces (label, etc)

The issue that I have come across is that the barcode (not controlled by me) has spaces in it.  If the Keyboard focus is in a Textbox or Button, the spaces are recorded in that control (i.e.  if button, causes a click) and does not go through the PreviewTextInput in my Shell.xaml

I would like to do one of the following

1. how to make the Shell preview those characters instead of the control with focus
2. once I get StartOfTransmission, move focus to my Shell, then after EndOfTransmission, set focus back to the control
3. Or some other way I am unaware of

Comment: I have tried Keyboard.ClearFocus(), but then it stops reading characters all together.

Comment: Is there a reason that you are using the barcode scanner that you are?  I usually opt for serial devices when working with this type of hardware.  Then, you can simply read from the serial port without worrying where your focus is.

Comment: it is a USB scanner (Intermec).  It is the scanner that our customer has so we are doing our testing with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found something that works.. but I don't Like it.

In my Shell.Xaml, I added the following..

```
<TextBlock x:Name="lblBarcodeFocus" Focusable="True" Width="0" Height="0" />
```

Then in my processing code, if I detect a "StartOfTransmission", I set focus to this control, (remembering what had focus), then after I am done processing, I set focus back to the original control.

There has to be a more "elegant" way of doing this... but I can move on to other issues :-)

Answer (score 1):

This works for me.

```
const string BEGINTEXT = "[";
const string ENDTEXT = "]";
StringBuilder _command;

private void Window_PreviewTextInput(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
{
  if(e.Text==BEGINTEXT)
  {
    _command = new StringBuilder();
  }
  else if(_command != null)
  {
    if(e.Text == ENDTEXT)
    {
      MessageBox.Show(_command.ToString());
      _command = null;
    }
    else
    {
      _command.Append(e.Text);
    }
  }
}
```